# Setting ArrayList entries as ViewFlipper children

Tags: java, android, viewflipper

There are over 30 views to be displayed in my activity. Each one is a RelativeLayout with nested ImageView and some TextViews within (some of them are static, some of them are variable). Refactored to programmatic way of displaying results it looks like:

```
tbnImages = db.getTbnImages();
tbnNames = db.getTbnNames();
tbnExts = db.getTbnExts();
tbnDescs = db.getTbnDescs();

vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipperTbnImages);
vf.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.left_in));
vf.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.left_out));

detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this, this);

tbnImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tbnImage); 
tbnName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tbnName);        
tbnExt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tbnExt);      
tbnDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tbnDesc);
```

How should I configure my ViewFlipper so that `.showNext()` and `.showPrevious()` methods would display proper views, including correct behaviour when launching method upon the last view (`.showNext()` redirects to the first view) and the first one (`.showPrevious()` presents the last view)?

```
public void onSwipe(int direction) {

switch (direction) {

    case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT:
        vf.showPrevious();
        break;

    case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT:
        vf.showNext();
        break;
    }
```

All variables (ImageView picture and TextView texts) are taken from an ArrayList. How to set them as ViewFlipper children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate all the 30 views and add them as children of the ViewFlipper. If all your views share one single layout, you should create a custom view to handle it.

```
public class CustomView extends RelativeLayout{

    public CustomView(Context context, Uri imageUri, String tbnName, String tbnDescripton, String tbnDesc) {
        super(context);

        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_layout_resource, this, true);

        ImageView tbnImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tbnImage);
        TextView tbnName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tbnName);
        TextView tbnExt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tbnExt);
        TextView tbnDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tbnDesc);

        tbnImage.setImageURI(imageUri);
        tbnName.setText(tbnName);
        tbnImage.setText(tbnDescription);
        tbnExt.setText(tbnDesc);
    }
}
```

Where 'your_layout_resource' is your current RelativeLayout resource with a 'merge' element as a root. Then you just have to create all the views you need and add them to your ViewFlipper:

```
    for(int i = 0; i<tbnImages.size(); i++){
        vf.addView(new CustomView(context,
                tbnImages.get(i),
                tbnNames.get(i),
                tbnDescripton.get(i),
                tbnDescs.get(i)));
    }
```

Anyway, 30 views are a lot of views. Are you sure a ViewPager wouldn't work for you?

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks!
Regarding the ViewPager: I think of adding this to one of my future projects so when I'm more familiar with that maybe I'll refactor the code. Thanks for mentioning, I almost forgot about this layout manager :-)