# startActivityFromChild calling from source activity to target activity

Tags: android

If I have some views nested in ViewFlipper as its children (all of them were added programmatically - [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18968842/1737830)), how can I refer to a specific one using the method:

`startActivityFromChild(getParent(), new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class), ???);`

which is called from `SourceActivity.class`?

Initially, I was trying to use something like:

`TargetActivity.getViewFlipper().setDisplayedChild(arg);`

but `startActivityFromChild()` requires an `int` as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to achieve what I wanted.

Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7325248/1737830), I created an `Intent` in my `SourceActivity`, setting an `int` value as an argument to be passed to the `TargetActivity`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TargetActivity.class);
i.putExtra("selectedChild", selChildInt);
startActivity(i);
```

After the value is passed, the `TargetActivity` receives it and parses:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
     viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(extras.getInt("selectedChild", 0));
}
```

And that's it :-)